# When is a $2$-lift of a graph connected?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, sp.spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory, covering-spaces

Let $\ (V\ E)\ $ be a graph, i.e. $\ E\subseteq\binom V2.\ $ A $2$-lift  pattern of a graph is a function $\ e:E\rightarrow\{-1\,\ 1\}.\ $ The induced 2-lift is defined as the graph $\ V\times\{-1\,\ 1\}\,\ E_e\ $ where

$$E_e\:=\ \{\{(a\ s)\,\ (b\ t)\}\ :\ \{a\ b\}\in V\ \ and\ \ t=e(\{a\ b\})\cdot s\}$$

- Now by looking at the $2$-lift pattern can one say if the lifted graph is connected or not?

Comment: Is this "abstract" matrix or matrix tied to the graph? In the former case, probably "no"; in the latter, certainly "yes".

Comment: Didn't get your question. I didn't define anything called the "abstract" matrix! I defined a "signing" matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still, I don't understand the question. The matrix determines the graph, hence there is a way to tell whether it's connected. If the question is about **how** to do that, then here is the first thing that comes to my mind:

> the double is connected iff
>   (1) the original graph $G$ is connected, and (2) the homomorphism $H_1(G)\to\Bbb Z_2$ defined by the $2$-lift pattern is nontrivial.

Condition (2) can be restated as follows: there is a $1$-cycle spanned by the original vertices $i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k,i_{k+1}=i_1$ such that $\prod_{j=1}^k e(\{i_j\ i_{j+1}\})=-1$.

Comment: You have answered the question. Then what do you still not understand about the question? :)

Comment: Can you give a reference to a proof of this condition that you stated? Is there a spectral way to check it?

Comment: Any textbook in algebraic topology. What you call a $2$-lift is a double covering. Such coverings over $G$ are classified by their characteristic classes $\omega\in H^1(G;\Bbb Z/2)$ and, assuming $G$ connected, the covering is connected iff $\omega\ne0$. The rest is a computation of $\omega$ in terms of cellular complexes. I don't know what "spectral" means in these settings.

Comment: I was asking if there is a reference you know which proves these for graphs. Like given a graph $G$, how would one calculate $H^1 (G, \mathbb{Z}/n)$? What other properties for general covering spaces go down to graph lifts?

Comment: It is not clear to me as to why the condition you said about product of signs along a cycle being $-1$ is the same as guaranteeing that the lift is non-trivial and hence that the cover is connected. I am missing these two implications. [...my algebraic topology is very rusty...] Can you may be sketch the idea if it is short?

Comment: Can you may be explain as to what is the map that you have in mind from $H^1(G) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$ ? Is that you are taking the signings along any loop in a homology class and mapping it to its product along the loop? But why product? Why not take addition modulo $n$ what is the group structure of $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: The map sends a loop to $+1$ iff its lift is a loop. (Strictly speaking, it is defined on $\pi_1$, but, since the target is abelian, it factors through $H_1$.) The group operation on $\{\pm1\}$ is the multiplication. For connectedness, you need at least one path connecting two points in the same fiber, i.e., a loop that does not lift to a loop (i.e., is sent to $-1$). Graph lifts **are** covering spaces, so all properties go down. For more than double coverings, it is a bit more complicated, so ask specific questions.

Comment: Are you saying that a loop on the graph will have an unique lift to the cover? For $\mathbb{Z}_n$ lifts of graphs can't one make the same statement about the complex $n$-roots of unity along some loop multiplying into a non-real root of unity for the lift to be connected?

Comment: I guess the idea was that one can have multiple lifts of loops but two lifts coincide if they coincide entirely if they coincide even at one point - right?

Comment: Yes, this is called "path lifting lemma". Of course, for graphs, this is all an overkill, but why to develop a separate theory?

Comment: I am not getting you. You say, "The map sends a loop to +1 iff its lift is a loop" - the lift of a loop on the base graph is not unique - then how is this map being decided?

Comment: Any double covering is regular (or Galois, as some say); in this situation, the property "to lift to a loop" does not depend on the lift. More generally, identifying the fiber over $x_0$ with the deck translation group $G$, for a lift $\gamma$ of a loop at $x_0$ you have $\gamma(1)=\gamma(0)\cdot g$, and this $g\in G$ is independent of the lift, just because any two lifts are related by a deck translation.

Comment: Can you explain why the existence of even 1 loop in the base graph along which the signs multiply to $-1$ ensures connectivity for the entire lift?

Comment: You should really read a textbook. Given two points $x_0$, $x_1$, you can connect $x_1$ to either $x_0$ or $tx_0$ (by a lift of a path connecting their projections). But since you can also connect $x_0$ and $tx_0$, you're done.

Comment: I am searching for a book if it deals with n-lifts of graphs. A $\mathbb{Z}_n$ lift is specified by assigning one of the n^th roots of unity to each of the edges. So I guess you are agreeing with me that if a product is taken over the complex roots of unity assigned on the edges then the lift is connected iff there exists at least 1 loop in the base graph such that the product of the complex roots of unity along it is not $1$ - right?

Comment: No. The corresponding homomorphism $H_1\to\Bbb Z_n$ must be surjective, not just nontrivial. Or, equivalently, you should have a loop sent to a **primitive** root of unity.

Comment: Can you give a reference for this?

Comment: Same: any textbook :) At least, you should be able to connect a fixed point with any other point in its fiber, and this is the surjectivity. On the other hand, this is also sufficient: same as the $\Bbb Z_2$ case. All equivalent restatements would follow from the fact that we are speaking about a homomorphism of abelian groups.